# Error: EACCES: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/emilio/.ionic/daemon.log' at Error (native)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hi Ionic community !

I am on a Ionic v3 project and it was working fine until I tried to add the `Geolocation` module from @ionic-native/geolocation so I 've got this error message : `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/emilio/.ionic/daemon.log'
    at Error (native)`
 when I try to run a Ionic serve`command in my bash terminal (I am on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6

If you need any other infos I am around

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tired to run it under SUDO ?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi wow it works !!!

Comment: can you rate it if it works? .. so toher people know it is the right answer .. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the directory /Users/emilio/.ionic/. It works for me...

Comment: wooow thanks It works really great !!! After removing the folder I  restart my pc then it works perfectly...also according to this issue I advise you to use `homebrew`and `yarn package manager``

Answer (score 1):

try to run it with `SUDO` privileges ...

hope it help you!!

Comment: try to install this package ... RIMRAF .. the run sudo rimraf FOLDERYOUWANTTODELTE